# File Uploader with image preview

Tags: acumatica

We have 3 image uploaders with image preview on a form.
When user uploads a picture on first uploader the image is shown other elements too.
Is there a possibility to separate these 3 elements in order to restrict the mention behavior?

In a way that each element shows their own images.

Comment: Could you please clarify, do all 3 images belong to the same record in the database or to 3 different records?

Comment: @RuslanDev It belongs to the same record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that **AllowNoImage** property set to ***True*** for all 3 **PXImageUploader** controls appears to be the answer: unless **AllowNoImage** property is set to ***True***, a **PXImageUploader** will always show the first picture attached to the record.

```
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True" LabelsWidth="XS" ControlSize="XM" />
<px:PXImageUploader ID="imgUploader" runat="server" DataField="ImageUrl" 
    AllowUpload="true" ShowComment="true" DataMember="ItemSettings" AllowNoImage="true"
    Height="320px" Width="390px" />
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="XS" ControlSize="XM" />
<px:PXImageUploader ID="imgUploader2" runat="server" DataField="UsrImageUrl2" 
    AllowUpload="true" ShowComment="true" DataMember="ItemSettings" AllowNoImage="true"
    Height="320px" Width="390px" />
<px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="XS" ControlSize="XM" />
<px:PXImageUploader ID="imgUploader3" runat="server" DataField="UsrImageUrl3" 
    AllowUpload="true" ShowComment="true" DataMember="ItemSettings" AllowNoImage="true" 
    Height="320px" Width="390px" />
```

[image]
To get the result shown above on the **Stock Items** screen, I also defined 2 custom DB-bound fields for the **InventoryItem** DAC (see code snippet below) and made sure to specify different DAC field name for the **DataField** property of every **PXImageUploader**:

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
{
    public abstract class usrImageUrl2 : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Image")]
    public string UsrImageUrl2 { get; set; }

    public abstract class usrImageUrl3 : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Image")]
    public string UsrImageUrl3 { get; set; }
}
```

In order to hide navigation buttons (" ***<-Ctrl*** " and " ***Ctrl->*** ") in all **PXImageUploader** controls, you should subscripbe to **Initialize** event of the container controls hosting **PXImageUploader** controls:

```
<px:PXTab ID="tab" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="606px" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="ItemSettings">
    <ClientEvents Initialize="tabInitialized" />
    <Items>
        ...
    </Items>
</px:PXTab>
```

and implement JavaScript function following the sample below:

```
function tabInitialized(s, a) {
    var leftArrows = document.getElementsByClassName("imgleft");
    for (var i = 0; i < leftArrows.length; i++) {
        leftArrows[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    var leftArrows = document.getElementsByClassName("imgright");
    for (var i = 0; i < leftArrows.length; i++) {
        leftArrows[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

To package custom JavaScript code into customization, in Layout Editor you should drag and drop a **Java Script** element from the **Add Controls** tab and copy your entire JavaScript code into its **Script** property.

Comment: Should we change visibility of the Next and Preview arrows on the preview panel?

Comment: @AndroLomtadze, please check the updated answer above.